# Как разместить первое фото с инсты на сайт?

Tags: wordpress, instagram

И что бы при обновлении фото тоже менялось? кто знает у них есть веб сервисы?

Comment: По простому запросу WordPress Instagram plugin первая строка в выдаче - сразу 8 лучших плагинов: https://athemes.com/collections/best-wordpress-instagram-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

Используйте плагин "Smash Balloon Social Photo Feed":
https://wordpress.org/plugins/instagram-feed/